# Show data after dropdown selection

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am struggling with my code. I want to show data from a specific user on screen. When the second dropdown is selected with the user from a specific group, I want his records to be shown on screen. But what ever I try, the data stays the same from one user. In a later stadium I want to make an Else and say if there is no data, that there is no data of the person. Should I do something with a jquery, or is there an easier way to solve this?

[image: The first dropdown is the group, the second the user.]
The first dropdown is the group, the second dropdown the user.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class DisplayGroups(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class DisplayUsername(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class CijferLijst(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    vak1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    cijfer1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default='1.0')
    vak2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    cijfer2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default='1.0')
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s'%(self.name, self.vak1, self.cijfer1, self.vak2, self.cijfer2, self.username)
```

**bekijk.html**

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Cijfers studenten{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $select1 = $('#groupdd1'),
            $select2 = $('#userdd1'),
            $options = $select2.find('option');
            $select1.on('change', function()
            {
                $select2.html($options.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
            }).trigger('change');
    });


</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_staff %}
<h1>Studentresultaten</h1>
<select id="groupdd1">
    <option disabled="true" selected>Kies een groep</option>
    {% for result in DisplayGroups %}
    <option>{{result}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="userdd1">
    <option disabled="true" selected>Kies een gebruiker</option>
    {% for result in DisplayUsername %}
    <option value="{{result.username}}">{{result}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endif %}


<br/>
{% for antwoord in CijferLijst %}
<h2>{{antwoord.name}}</h2>
<div class="container px-4">
    <div class="row justify content-start gx-5">
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light"><strong>Vaknaam</strong></div>
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light"><strong>Cijfer</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row gx-5 justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light">{{antwoord.vak1}}</div>
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light">{{antwoord.cijfer1}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row gx-5 justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light">{{antwoord.vak2}}</div>
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light">{{antwoord.cijfer2}}</div>
        <div class="col-5 border bg-light">{{antwoord.username}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import DisplayGroups, DisplayUsername, CijferLijst
from .forms import Grades
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    response = redirect('/login')
    return response


def home(response):
    return render(response, "home/home.html")


def bekijk(request):
    DisplayGroup = Group.objects.all()
    print(DisplayGroup)
    DisplayNames = User.objects.all()
    print(DisplayNames)
    Cijfer = CijferLijst.objects.all()
    print(Cijfer)

    return render(request, "home/bekijk.html",
                  {"DisplayGroups": DisplayGroup, "DisplayUsername": DisplayNames, "CijferLijst": Cijfer})


def cijfers(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Grades(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form)
            return redirect('gelukt')

    else:
        form = Grades()
    return render(request, "home/cijfers.html", {"form":form})


def done(response):
    return render(response, "home/gelukt.html")
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import CijferLijst
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Grades(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    vak1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    cijfer1 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    vak2 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    cijfer2 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    username = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    check = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = CijferLijst
        fields = ['name', 'vak1', 'cijfer1', 'vak2', 'cijfer2', 'username']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well this has all to do with a form and showing/updating it, but I want the form data that is in my database to show on the screen, when I select the second dropdown (see picture). So I am sorry, this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: u want like the page does not refreshes and the 2nd user's data shows up?

Comment: @VisheshMangla well when I choose the second dropdown, I want the grades to pop up, if that is with a refresh or not, that does not matter. But I do not know how to ask the program to give me that information. Or the query that goes with it, to make it work.

Comment: what you need is to set an eventlistener  and on select make it `fetch` data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: from the server you can ask for a json response. It's related to javascript

Comment: @VisheshMangla I will try that tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks for your help already!